Git push on new linux system results in authentication failure with same config files
I recently got a new desktop machine, because my hardware was old and out of date.  I saved everything, and got a new machine with an updated Ubuntu (22.04)
I was able to clone one (hmm, actually more than one) of my repositories just fine.  But when I pushed I got:
remote:  Invalid username or password.
fatal:  Athentication failed for 'https://github.com/gischer/<my repository>.git/'

My global .gitconfig looks like this:
[user]
    email = <my email>
    name = gischer
[credential]
    helper = cache
[url "https://api:<stuff that looks like a token>@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com

My local .git/config looks like this:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/gischer/<my repository>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remots/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    name = gischer
    email = <my email>

This worked a week or so ago on my old system.  I don't remember configuring this exactly, it has been quite a while.  I can't find any reference to the api:[token] url as such, so I don't really know what's going on.
Any thoughts?

What about your public-private ssh keys? (in ~/.ssh)

ssh keys wont matter since he's not using git or ssh protocolsl. he's using https, which means likely his old credentials had his GITTOKEN in his crednetials but his new box doesnt have that.

Authentication to public repos isn't required for reading, only for writing (pushing).
Unless you still have access to your GIT_TOKEN from the old box that you registered with github, you will probably need to establish a new token to use.
with github, when you use https based push you have to authenticate each time, and you had it setup with the user in your global .gitconfig, and your global also had a credential store setup which presumably had your old GIT_TOKEN stored in it.
See this documentation to create a new one from GitHub
It's possible in your old thing you had doctored that URL to include the token, but I'm not familiar with that practice and can't recommend it since you are putting your token out in plaintext on the box. ( but then again so does using the basic credential cache... sigh)

I think you are right about putting the token out in plaintext.  The best I can remember is that I followed some recipe somewhere that doesn't seem to exist now.

Oh, you seem to imply that a GIT_TOKEN will only work from one machine, and that I would need a new one for the new machine?  Do I have that right?

no, i don't. the token will work from anywhere.. I just dont know if you have the token to bring with you. There is no way to recover the token from github

that said in your shoes i would generate a new token, and revoke the old one.

What I did was switch to using ssh, which transferred over just fine from the old machine.  It's working well, though I guess there might be issues at some point.

thats a great solution IMHO
